# How to install and use the Chart.js package locally?

Tags: javascript, html, bash, npm, chart.js

This should be really simple, but I seem to struggle. I tried to install `chart.js` using npm on my Raspberry Pi, since for my project I cannot use an online version.

Basically, I navigated to my project folder (`cd my_project`), and then used `npm init -y` and `npm install chart.js`. From what I can see, the installation was successful.

Afterwards, i simply created a html file to test it out:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  <script src="/node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js"></script>
  <script>
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Test Dataset',
          data: [10, 20, 15],
          backgroundColor: ['red', 'green', 'blue'],
        }]
      },
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, the result is a black page. What went wrong?

Comment: What server you are using to test out?

Comment: No server at all - I just tried to open the html file in the browser.

Comment: Heres a quick explanation on what [umd](https://jameshfisher.com/2020/10/04/what-are-umd-modules/) modules are. That should help understanding why it works.

Comment: We don't do SOLVED in the title here. If you found your own answer you can post and accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your browser's developer tools. Look at the console. Read the error messages.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

*chart.js* is a [module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) (specifically an ECMAScript module).

Browsers support these under a few conditions:

- ✓ You load the `<script>` with `type="module"` (which you didn't, but this is easily fixed)
- ✓ You load the URL from HTTP(S) and not a file scheme URL (which you didn't, but this is easily fixed)
- ✓  The module doesn't depend on APIs not provided by browsers (Chart.js is designed to run in browsers so this is fine)
- ⚠   The `import` statements use URLs (here is the sticking point, *chart.js* has `import '@kurkle/color';` which depends on Node.js style module resolution).

*chart.js* is intended to be used in combination with a **bundler** such as [parcel](https://parceljs.org/), [vite](https://vitejs.dev/), or [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) — and you aren't using one of them.

---

*chart.umd.js* is the same code presented as a [UMD module](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) instead of an ECMAScript module.

This format does a lot of inlining and rewriting so it "just works" in more places (including when loaded in a browser with a regular `<script>`)

---

Note that [the Chart.js documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/integration.html) tells you to use the umd version if you aren't using a bundler.